# QWebView vs QWebPage

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyside, qwebview, qwebpage

The documentation (in PyQt at least) for `QWebView` says: 'The QWebView class provides a widget that is used to view and edit web documents', whereas `QWebPage` says: 'The QWebPage class provides an object to view and edit web documents'.  Given that these effectively mean the same thing:

- Is there a historical reason why these 2 classes evolved?
- Is one any better to use than the other in any particular circumstance?

(This stems from the fact the I'm using a javascript library embedded within a PyQt application; I'm currently using `QWebView`, but only `QWebPage` has a method for [catching javascript errors](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qwebpage.html#javaScriptConsoleMessage), so was considering whether it was worth translating my code to subclass `QwebPage` instead)

Answer (score 7):

From the [documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwebpage.html) it says

> QWebPage holds a main frame responsible for web content, settings, the
>   history of navigated links and actions. This class can be used,
>   together with QWebFrame, to provide functionality like QWebView in a
>   widget-less environment.

Also `QWebView` inherits from `QWidget` while `QWebPage` does not.

My guess is therefore that `QWebView` is just a widget being able to load and display HTML while `QWebPage` can be used with a view or without a view. Also `QWebPage` has more functionality like settings or history of nagivation.

Now a widget-less environment is for example `QtCore.QCoreApplication`.

It seems that you would use `QWebPage` for example when writting an application for scraping web content while you would prefer `QWebView` when you just want to load and display some web content somewhere in your application. `QWebView` being a widget will always want to display something.

Historically they were both introduced with Qt 4.4.

The open questions are how much they share internally and if there is something you cannot do or cannot emulate with `QWebView` that you can do with `QWebPage`?

Answer (score 0):

`QWebView` is a `QWidget` that owns a `QWebPage`. If you build a widget-based application, use `QWebView` and set your own page with [`QWebView::setPage()`](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qwebview.html#setPage). Of course, you can pass an object of a `QWebPage` subclass to that function.

You can access the current page of the widget with [`QWebView::page()`](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qwebview.html#page).